# Show Azure ADB2C login controls in 2 columns

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

**Description:**

1. I have created a unified.html file and uploaded to a storage account which is then used in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml

[image]

2. I am trying to change the below Azure ADB2C control structure (in the HTML file) to appear in 2 different columns instead of having in a single column.

[image]

**Steps taken:**

1. For the above control structure to be used, we need `<div id="api">`.
   I tried using the following div structure:

   ```
     <div class="table-row">
        <div id ="api" class="col">
           <div class="options">
              <button class="accountButton firstButton claims-provider-selection" id="GoogleExchange">Google</button>
              <button class="accountButton claims-provider-selection" id="FacebookExchange">Facebook</button>
              <button class="accountButton claims-provider-selection" id="MicrosoftExchange">Microsoft Account</button>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
           <div>
              <input id="email" type="text" name="u" placeholder="Username" required="required" />                  
              <input id="password" type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
              <a id="forgotPassword" href="https://bing.com">Forgot Password</a>
              <button id="next" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Sign in</button>
              Don't have an account            <a id="createAccount" href="https://microsoft.com">Sign up now</a><!---->
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   ```

But that also gives me the Azure ADB2C login controls in a single column.

[image]

**Resolution required:**

Is there any way I can have the following structure:
[image]